# Tabs&Grid in Vaadin 12

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I choose Vaadin for building my very simple UI within the spring boot application.

I have:

```
@Route
@PWA(name = "Signing certificates manager", shortName = "CertMgr")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Certificates");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Users");

        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(tab1, tab2);

        CertView certView = new CertView();
        certView.setVisible(false);
        UserView userView = new UserView(addUsers());
        userView.setVisible(true);

        Map<Tab, Component> tabsToPages = new HashMap<>();
        tabsToPages.put(tab1, certView);
        tabsToPages.put(tab2, userView);

        Div pages = new Div(certView, userView);

        Set<Component> pagesShown = Stream.of(userView)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(event -> {
            pagesShown.forEach(page -> page.setVisible(false));
            pagesShown.clear();
            Component selectedPage = tabsToPages.get(tabs.getSelectedTab());
            selectedPage.setVisible(true);
            pagesShown.add(selectedPage);
        });

        add(tabs, pages);
    }

    private List<User> addUsers() {
        return new LinkedList<User>() {{
            add(new User("qewr", "asdf", "xzcv"));
        }};
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UserView extends VerticalLayout {
    Grid<User> grid;

    public UserView(List<User> users) {
        grid = new Grid<>(User.class);
        grid.setItems(users);

        grid.addColumn(User::getMail).setHeader("mail");
        grid.addColumn(User::getName).setHeader("name");
        grid.addColumn(User::getPass).setHeader("pass");

        grid.addSelectionListener(event -> {
            List<User> selected = (List<User>) event.getAllSelectedItems();
            add(new UserRow(selected.get(0)));
        });

        add(grid);
    }
}
```

and the result of this is a view like this:
[image: and the result of this is a view like this:]

so you can see, the grid has no width and is too long (I have only one user there)

I am new to Vaadin so I am surely doing something wrong, but basically this is [vaadin tabs](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-tabs) handling from the samples.

My questions are:
how do I draw the grid properly with my current setup?
is it possible to display a view from completely different page when clicking on tab with that page would have it's own context and could use spring's DI? like to have autonomous page and not coupled objects like I have now. or advice the best pattern to handle this with vaadin, please.

Vaadin: 12.0.7

Spring-Boot: 2.1.2.RELEASE

Hope you get my point.

Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do

```
Div pages = new Div(certView, userView);
    pages.setSizeFull();
```